# Eclipse: Can't kill process on Java perspective

Tags: java, eclipse, unix

I am working on a Java project in Eclipse in Unix, and ran the project from the IDE. The process seems to run forever and doesn't respond to my clicks on the red "stop" button. I really want to avoid restarting my IDE. Can anyone advise how to kill the embedded process?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: are you sure that only one thread is running? If you have more than 1 Thread and you kill one you automaticly see another running thread.

Comment: Yes, it's a GUI project with Swing and definitely has multiple threads

Comment: You have to close all swing-windows. If you just want to terminate all java threads, do `killall java` in your OS terminal.

Comment: But it will kill also my Eclipse - wouldn't it?

Comment: I've figured it out! Exited from the Console tab and reopened it - then the `Remove All Terminated Launches` button became available, and I used it to kill everything. Now it's Ok. Thanks to all of you

Comment: `killall java` does not kill eclipse

Comment: @hewo `killall java` DOES KILL eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run in terminal

```
 jps -l
```

It will show you all running java processes.

Quick example. I run simple JFrame window.

[image]

As you can see there is clear process number for my JFrame. Just kill it and work with your Eclipse without restart.